# how to add bundle product item image in magento 1.9.x?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to add product in Bundle. Can anyone tell me how to do this? 
Since i am new to Magento please tell me briefly.
I have tried to add Name there it works finally but I want to add Images as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [a link](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/display-bundle-product-s-bundled-items-images-2.html)!.
It is compatible with 1.5, 1.6, 1.6.1, 1.6.2.0, 1.7, 1.8, 1.8.1, but if you want use in 1.9..x then you have to change some css and js file.